# Variável indefinida, Aplicação MVC PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Estou com o seguinte erro retornando no meu código

> Notice: Undefined variable: errors in D:\wamp\www\mvc\application\controllers\login.php on line 33

Este é meu Controller:

```
class Login extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        if (Input::exists()) {
            $validate = new Validate();

            $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                'username' => array(
                    'required' => true
                ),
                'password' => array(
                    'required' => true
                ),
            ));

            if ($validation->passed()) {
                //logic code for this if
            } else {
                $errors = $validation->errors();
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'title' => WEB_TITLE,
            'validation' => $errors
        ];

        $this->view->display('templates/default/header', $data);
        $this->view->display('login/index', $data);
        $this->view->display('templates/default/footer', $data);
    }

}
```

E esta é a minha View:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h3 class="page-header">
                            Member login
                        </h3>

                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username or E-mail" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password" class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" name="loginBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-block">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Sign in
                            </button>
                        </form>

                        <?php
                       if ($data['validation']) {
                           echo $data['validation'][0];
                       }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="<?=Url::url_base()?>">Back to home!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Obs: o erro só some se eu colocar um `@` antes da minha variável `@$errors`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é o escopo de `$errors`, o que acontece se o código cair no if? `$error` não é criada/definida.

```
if ($validation->passed()) {
  //logic code for this if
} else {
   $errors = $validation->errors();
}

$data = ['title' => WEB_TITLE, 'validation' => $errors];
```

1 - Pode resolver isso definindo `$errors` como array vazio antes do if.

```
$errors = [];
if ($validation->passed()) {
```

2 - Se não tiver nenhuma lógica associada ao `else`, pode pegar os erros e definir na criação de `$data` isso elimina a variável `$errors`

```
$data = ['title' => WEB_TITLE, 'validation' => $validation->errors()];
```

Comment: Show rray, eu tinha feito isso porem eu retirei e esqueci de coloca-lo novamente. muito obrigado.

Comment: estou com outro erro diferente neste mesmo código será que você pode me ajudar? não encontro a solução: ` Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\wamp\www\humble\application\controllers\auth.php on line 46`

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO posso sim, criar uma pergunta nova, cm o código atualizado.

Comment: Pronto @rray http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128214/qual-o-motivo-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in