# Qual o motivo Trying to get property of non-object in?

Tags: php, mvc

Galera estou tentando retornar dados do banco usando este código:

```
//avoid Undefined variable
$errors = [];

if (Input::exists('post'))
{
    $validate = new Validate;

    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'required' => true
        )
    ));


    if ($validation->passed())
    {

        $data = $this->_model->get_member_hash(Input::get('username'));

        if (Password::password_verify(Input::get('password'), $data[0]->admin_password))
        {
            echo 'correct data';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'incorrect data';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors = $validation->errors();
    }
```

Só que ele está me retornando esses dois erros

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Qual motivo?

Meu model:

```
public function get_member_hash($username)
    {
        return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'admins WHERE admin_email=:email OR admin_username=:username', array(
            ':email'    => $username,
            ':username' => $username,
        ));
    }
```

Classe de validação

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class Input
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static function exists($type = 'post')
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
                break;

            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
                break;

            default :
                return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static function get($item)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$item]))
        {
            return trim(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $item)));
        }
        else if (isset($_GET[$item]))
        {
            return trim(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_GET, $item)));
        }

        //By default return string
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: ele alega que vc esta tenntado acessar uma propriedade que nao existe...ja olhou se esqueceu de declarar algum meodo?

Comment: Sim, todos os métodos que estou usando estão sendo declarados.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39694/discussion-between-guilherme-spinxo-and-rray).

Answer (score -1):

Não sei o que esse método retorna:

`public function get_member_hash($username)
    {
        return $this->_db->read('SELECT * FROM ' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'admins WHERE admin_email=:email OR admin_username=:username', array(
            ':email'    => $username,
            ':username' => $username,
        ));
    }`

No seu código você trata como se tivesse certeza que ele retorna um array quando você chama $data[0]

O problema é que esse método não está retornando um array, pois creio que a consulta não retornou nem um valor.

antes de chamar $data[0] você precisa fazer uma checagem, tipo:

`if(is_array($data){
//faz algo
} else {
 //não retornou nenhum valor
}`